# Indian e-visa photo rotated left (270 degrees)

Tags: india, e-visas

I have just received an Indian e-visa. The photo orientation of my photo is 270 degrees (the top of my head is facing left).

Is this normal?

Comment: It happens sometimes when people take a photo with their phone and didn't turn the phone to the side. I can't say whether India will accept it at immigration.

Answer (score 2):

Generally countries can be quite strict with visa photos and dimensions. Immigration officers can make all sorts of claims saying they can’t recognise if it’s you and really depends on the officer. I’ve had problems before laminating my document.

You don’t want to risk it as it really depends on the day. I say it’s worth.

It’s worth:

- cancelling your application and applying for a new visa (note your application won’t be refunded)
- using this phone number to contact: +91-22-2752 3816 or using this email: indian-evisa@gov.in

Hopefully your visa can then be reissued but you might need to pay a fee if it’s your own mistake submitting the photo like that.